# Replacing selected text in edittext textwatch issue

Tags: select, text, replace, android-edittext, textwatcher

edittext1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

```
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        selStart = edittext1.getSelectionStart();
        selEnd= edittext1.getSelectionEnd();
        lengthBefore = edittext1.getText().toString().length();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        int lengthAfter = edittext1.getText().toString().length() - lengthBefore;


        if(!(lengthAfter < 0))
        {
            String codedBefore = editTextCoded.getText().toString().substring(0, selStart);
            String codedAfter;
            if(selEnd>1) {
                codedAfter = editTextCoded.getText().toString().substring(selEnd);
            }
            else
            {
                codedAfter = "";
            }
            editTextCoded.setText(codedBefore);

            //Zakodowanie nowego

            String toBeCoded = edittext1.getText().toString().substring(selStart, selEnd+ lengthAfter);
            for(int i=0; i<toBeCoded.length(); i++)
            {
                newChar = toBeCoded.charAt(i);

                    editTextCoded.setText(editTextCoded.getText().toString() + Character.toString(newChar));
            }

            //Dopisanie końcówki tłumaczenia
            editTextCoded.setText(editTextCoded.getText().toString() + codedAfter);

        }
        else
        {
            String codedBefore = editTextCoded.getText().toString().substring(0, selStart + lengthAfter);
            String codedAfter = editTextCoded.getText().toString().substring(selStart, editTextCoded.length());

            editTextCoded.setText(codedBefore + codedAfter);

        }
    }

});
```

after this operation editTextCoded and edittext1 should show the same text, yet when I copy part of the text, then select another (smaller) part and paste it replacing the selected part, the text in editTextCoded and edittext1 differs.

Anyone could please help me? I have no ideas left what to do with it.